# Fontes não carregam corretamente no IE8

Tags: css

Estou utilizando ambas fontes em um site:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Abrem corretamente em todos os navegadores, porém no IE8 não. Existe algum fix pra isso?
Ou terei que baixar as fontes e usar `@font-face`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experimente colocar cada estilo de fonte em um link separado:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- ... -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Para evitar tantos links em navegadores que não tem esse problema, use comentários condicionais:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--[if (!IE)|(gt IE 8)]>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Funcionou, o IE8 não renderizou muito bem a fonte, mas já tá valendo! :D

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta pois tinha esquecido de considerar os outros navegadores, `!IE`.